# Mongoose findOneAndUpdate: Is there a way to update object in subdocument?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a model like this:

// Document

```
var programSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String
    },
    session: [sessionSchema]
}, {
    timestamps: true
});
```

// Subdocument

```
var sessionSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String
    },
    info: {
        type: String
    },
    order: {
        type: Number
    }
}, {
    timestamps: true
});
```

Is there a way to access the subdocuments object and edit if exists, else create new?

I figured something like this:

```
 router.post('/createsession', function (req, res) {

        var options = { upsert: true, new: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true };

        var SessionData = req.body.session;

        if (!SessionData.id) {
            SessionData.id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId();
        }

        Program.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.body.session.id }, { $push: { session: SessionData } }, options, function (err, session) {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(409).json({
                    success: false,
                    message: 'Error creating/updating session'
                });
            } else {
                return res.status(200).json({
                    success: true,
                    session: session
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

This only creates a new document. Would I be able to edit existing with this same query?

Comment: Why not just make `session` an array of references?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
      var options = { upsert: true};

  Program.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.body.session.id }, { $set: {
                   //Set individually values
               name: req.nnae,

              } }, 
               options, function (err, session) {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(409).json({
                    success: false,
                    message: 'Error creating/updating session'
                });
            } else {
                return res.status(200).json({
                    success: true,
                    session: session
                });
            }
        });
    });
```